# Numerically solving a steady state equation (diffusion reaction with monod kinetics)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a system that I'm interating in time via finite differences, but one of the equations is to be solved at steady state each iteration:

$D\Delta S=\frac{S}{S+a}\rho$

I want to solve it via a multigrid approach, and to do so I need to set up an equation of the form $Ax=b$. I know how to construct my laplacian ($A$)and how to include my boundary values in $b$, but I can't figure out how to deal with the $\frac{S}{S+a}$, (a and D are constants, by the way).

Does this need to be solved implicitly? If so, are there any references that I might learn how to figure out how that works? I'm quite inexperienced when it comes to converting to numerical problems.

Really, the issue comes from the $1/S$, because if it wasn't there then I could just build A as something like $(I-L)$, where I is the identity matrix and L is my laplacian matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a semilinear equation that requires an iterative solution.  Here is an article that proposes an approach:

Timmermann, Gisela. "A cascadic multigrid algorithm for semilinear elliptic problems." Numerische Mathematik 86.4 (2000): 717-731.